# How to simply have python print "\xaa\xbb\xcc\xdd" as 0xddccbbaa?

Tags: python, hex

I believe I'm misunderstanding something that should probably be simple.

I'm trying to accept arguments passed to a python script. The type of argument I'm expecting is somewhere along the lines of `"\xaa\xbb\xcc\xdd"`, and it keeps converting it to binary(i think?) instead of actually allowing me to print it out just how it was passed.

How can I get this to do what I'm looking for it to do? I'd ultimately like to take this and be able to convert it to something like `0xddccbbaa`, but I guess I'd at least like to get the first step completed by being able to interpret it.

Like, I don't want printing `\x75` to print out a `u`. I want to be able to interpret `\x75` as `\x75` . Any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some demonstrations with [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html):

```
x = b"\xaa\xbb\xcc\xdd"

import struct

struct.unpack('I',x)
Out[3]: (3721182122,)

y = struct.unpack('I',x)

y[0]
Out[5]: 3721182122

hex(y[0])
Out[6]: '0xddccbbaa'
```

Essentially: treat the bytestring as a little-endian 4-byte unsigned integer (`'I'`).  `struct` handles turning it into an `int`, and you can use `hex` to get a string representation of it in hex (or use something like `'{:x}'.format(y[0])`, if you prefer)

Comment: THANK YOU! This solved what I was looking for. Can't believe I couldn't figure this out. Many thanks man!