# How to simply have python print '\xd2\xbb' as 0xd2bb?

Tags: python, struct, hex

In Python 2.7, I want to change a bytestring '\xd2\xbb' into hex 0xd2bb.

I think this problem is pretty close to the question below.

[How to simply have python print "\xaa\xbb\xcc\xdd" as 0xddccbbaa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039054/how-to-simply-have-python-print-xaa-xbb-xcc-xdd-as-0xddccbbaa/23039063#23039063)

but I have no idea how to apply the struct.unpack() methods to my case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to simply have python print "\xaa\xbb\xcc\xdd" as 0xddccbbaa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039054/how-to-simply-have-python-print-xaa-xbb-xcc-xdd-as-0xddccbbaa) :)

Comment: Look at [endianess](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) and [format characters](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/struct.html#format-characters) of the struct module.

Comment: @msvalkon Oh there it is! Thank you so much